# How to add an empty line in css

Tags: css

I want to add an empty line above `span` tag in css using `:before` attribute like this.

```
______

 Hi
```

I've tried using `border-top` for `span` tag. But that's not my requirement. 
I searched and tried but didn't work. Please help.

Comment: have you tried to set `display: block;` to that span tag ?

Comment: Why insisting on "using :before attribute"? Is this homework? Common way is simply have margin.

Comment: Not specifically, One more thing, I am using the same span attribute in another page, there I don't want _____ to be displayed...what should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are set on using the `:before` attribute, see below:

```css
span:before {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  background: red; /* Remove, just showing empty line */
}
span {
  display: inline-block; /* Can remove if span:before width doesn't matter. */
}
```

```html
<span>Test Text</span>
```

If you're open to using something a bit simpler, try using `margin-top` by using the following code:

```css
span {
  margin-top: 1em; /* Adjust to your liking */
  display: block; /* Could also use inline-block */
}
```

```html
<span>Test Text</span>
```

Comment: One more thing, I am using the same span attribute in another page, there I don't want _____ to be displayed...what should I do?

Comment: You should add a CSS class or ID to the `span`. You could do `<span class="line">Test Text</span>` and then update the CSS so it only targets `span.line` by using something like `span.line { margin-top: 1em; display: block; }`

Comment: Thanks. But I am using the same span and same class in another page. Where I dont want the line to be displayed on new page.

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: block` and `margin-top: 1em`.
`<span>` is an element with a default display value of inline. You should use a div or set the display to block.

`em` equals to the font size, so it should do the work for the margin-top

**HTML**

```
<span class="example">Hi</span>
```

**CSS**

```
.example{
  margin-top: 1em;
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
span:before {
  content: "\a";
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<span>Hi</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `margin-top: 1em;` that will give a white space of one line above your `tag`.